# Why isn't $f(x) = x \sin(x)$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

we were asked to prove or disprove the mentioned function to be uniformly continuous.
I tried the following:

$$|f(z) - f(w)| = |z \sin(z) - w \sin(w)| ≤ |z+w|$$ and thus fulfilling the Hölder condition of continuity.
I assumed $|sin(x)| ≤ 1$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

We later showed that f is NOT uniformly continuous. I understood that proof, but I cannot find my mistake here.

Comment: How exactly is $f$ Hölder continuous with that inequality?

Comment: I don't understand your conclusion. What would be values $\alpha, C$ such that $\forall z,\forall w, \lvert f(z)-f(w)\rvert\le C\lvert z-w\rvert^\alpha$ ?

Comment: Oh, that's a typo. I meant:

≤ |z+w| 

Why can't I state that? The absolute value of sin is between -1 and 1 , right? Or does it specifically have to be |z-w| ?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $|f(z)-f(w)| \le |z+w|$ does not even imply that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I believe you are thinking of the condition $|f(z)-f(w)| \leq |z-w|$. It is important that  both sides go to zero as $z\to w$.

Comment: For the record, $\lvert 6\sin 6-(-7)\sin (-7)\rvert\approx 6.2754>\lvert 6+(-7)\rvert$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could differentiate your obeject function: $(x \sin x)'= \sin x+x \cos x$.

Plug in a sequence $x=2n\pi(n\geq 1)$ you could see that this derivative could gets super close to $+\infty$.

Being uniformly continuous requires that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ must stay below $\varepsilon$ as long as $|x_1-x_2|$ is no larger than some constant $\delta$. This cannot happen if the derivative can be arbitrarily close to $\infty$. For example, choosing $x_1,x_2$ both near $2n\pi(n\geq 1)$ with distance some small $\delta$, as $n$ increases, the $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$, which is roughly $\delta$ times the derivative, must eventually gets very large.

And your mistake is that: yes, the right-hand side must be $|z-w|$ instead of $|z+w|$.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about this test!